# Cannot find package for Python 3.7.8

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am completly new to Conda and I have been struggling for a day without success.

I would like to use [the `pvtrace` module](https://github.com/danieljfarrell/pvtrace). [The documentation](https://github.com/danieljfarrell/pvtrace/blob/master/README.md#linux-and-windows-using-conda) specifically says to run the following commands to install the package:

```
conda create --name pvtrace-env python=3.7.8
conda activate pvtrace-env
conda install Rtree
pip install pvtrace
```

I have the following error:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
  - python=3.7.8
```

I have Anaconda 3 which original Python version is 3.9. I installed the version 3.7, but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: which command raises the error?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but the **defaults** (**main**/**anaconda**) channels are missing specifically the Python 3.7.8 build. This is available through Conda Forge, so, instead try

```bash
## one should prefer to list all known package at creation
conda create -n pvtrace-env -c conda-forge python=3.7.8 pip rtree
conda activate pvtrace-env
pip install pvtrace
```

Alternatively, use a YAML file:

**pvtrace-env.yaml**

```yaml
name: pvtrace-env
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.7.8
  - rtree
  - pip
  - pip:
    - pvtrace
```

which is used as:

```bash
conda env create -n pvtrace-env -f pvtrace-env.yaml
```